# WDK: Casting PVOID to PWCHAR (C to C++ conversion)

Tags: c++, winapi, wdk

I am experimenting with a Windows driver and working with Microsofts driver code examples (Minispy to be exact). Unfortunately, i am pretty new to C++ and especially driver development.

While translating the user-mode application from C to C++ (most parts work very well by now), i encountered an interesting cast:

```
CHAR buffer[1024];
PINSTANCE_FULL_INFORMATION data = (PINSTANCE_FULL_INFORMATION)buffer;

hResult = FilterVolumeInstanceFindFirst(VolumeName,
        InstanceFullInformation,
        data,
        sizeof(buffer) - sizeof(WCHAR),
        &bytesReturned,
        &volumeIterator);

PWCHAR filtername = PVOID(PUCHAR(data) + data->FilterNameBufferOffset);
filtername[data->FilterNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR)] = L'\0';

if (_wcsicmp(filtername, MINISPY_NAME) == 0) { ...
```

This part of the code delivers an compiler error C2440: Cannot convert from PVOID to PWCHAR:

```
filtername = PVOID(PUCHAR(data) + data->FilterNameBufferOffset);
```

The code worked perfectly fine in C, but C++ won't cast that void pointer "array" to PWCHAR.

I tried for hours now, i could not get it to work. Any ideas?

Many thanks!

For reference:

The PINSTANCE_FULL_INFORMATION struct:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff548185(v=vs.85).aspx

The compiler error C2440:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx

Comment: of course `PVOID` can not be assigned to `PWCHAR` variable in *c++* . you need direct cast `PWCHAR filtername = (PWCHAR)(PUCHAR(data) + data->FilterNameBufferOffset);` or say `(PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(data, data->FilterNameBufferOffset)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
PWCHAR filtername = PWCHAR(PUCHAR(data) + data->FilterNameBufferOffset);
```

The reason is that C allows implicit casting of a `void*` to anything, while in C++ casting a `void*` has to be explicit.

So, this was in fact a slight mistake in the original C code which went unnoticed: the author was casting the `PUCHAR` to `PVOID`, and then assigning that to a `PWCHAR`.  The C compiler did not mind, because casting `PVOID` to anything can be done implicitly.  The C++ compiler does mind, requiring you to further cast `PVOID` to `PWCHAR`.  However, casting to `PVOID` was unnecessary in the first place: you can just cast the `PUCHAR` to `PWCHAR` without an intermediate cast to `PVOID`.